# Character Controllers not falling anymore

Tags: unity-game-engine, controller, game-physics

This question might already have been asked and answered somewhere, but I've seen no such situations mentioned on StackOverflow.

PROBLEM : Since a few days, my GameObjects who have a CharacterController component attahced do them do not obey to gravity anymore. They can move as expected on X and Z, but **will not fall to the ground in any case whatsoever.**

I do not think the problem comes from a script I made, because I made a test with an object completely clear of any code, and it was still stuck in the air. I thought it was a property I had modified by accident in only one of my projects, but it turns out the issue **impacts all of my Unity projects.**

Should I reinstall Unity, or recreate all my projects from scratch?

The object "3rd Person Player" is an empty, and the cylinder and head are parented to it.

EDIT: As asked by amitklein, here is an image of the view and inspector :

[[image: View and Inspector image]

EDIT 2 : As asked on reddit, here is the movement script :

[CODE]

```
// Character Controller
public CharacterController devonController;

//Values and movement tools
public float walkSpeed = 4.0f;
public float unchargedJumpForce = 10.0f;
public float chargedJumpForce;
public Vector3 floorMotionVector;
public Vector3 jumpVector;
public float Gravity = -9.81f;
void Start()
{
    devonController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update()
{
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    floorMotionVector = new Vector3(horizontal, 0, vertical).normalized;

    if(floorMotionVector.magnitude >= 0.1f && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        devonController.Move(floorMotionVector * (6 * walkSpeed) * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    else
    {
        devonController.Move(floorMotionVector * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

[/CODE]

Comment: Please add an image of the ridgitbody and charactercontroller from the inspector

Comment: I added the image

Comment: You don't have a Rigiditbody on your object to it doesn't use gravity

Comment: I read on the unity forums that adding a character controller component automaitcally enables gravity, and that using both character controller and rigidbody on the same gameObject is a very bad idea? Are these statements true?

Comment: `The Character Controller is mainly used for third-person or first-person player control that does not make use of Rigidbody
 physics.`
From https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html
I think that means that to use gravity you need to add the Rigidbody

Comment: @amitklein I added the code

Comment: Thanks, in anyway, try adding rigiditbody to the object, that should work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add gravity to the CharacterController.Move() function yourself.

*Note: If you use a rigidbody, the movement will need to be created differently. I would not mix the CharacterController and Rigidbody components. Their built in functionality will conflict and cause you problems. I recommend choosing one or the other.

For a CharacterController, create two properties in your class called `private float ySpeed;` and `public float gravity = 20;`

```
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    floorMotionVector = new Vector3(horizontal, 0, vertical).normalized;

    ySpeed -= gravity * Time.deltaTime; // Apply a constant gravity every frame
    floorMotionVector.y = ySpeed; // Apply gravity to your movement vector
    
    // update your CharacterController
    CharacterController.Move(MoveInput * Time.deltaTime);
```

- The `ySpeed` will track the Y axis of your movement vector separately. This allows you to do things like gravity and jumping.
- You then apply the ySpeed to your movement vector before sending the vector to CharacterController.Move().
- Time.deltaTime is applied when adding the gravity and again when sending your move vector to the Move function. This keeps the movement in sync with the framerate.

Hope that helps! Happy coding.